# Show $G$ is isomorphic to external direct product of finite Abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be finite Abelian group of order $n_1n_2\cdots n_r$. Let both $G$ and
$\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_r}$ contain
$\delta_1, \delta_2, \cdots, \delta_r$
number of elements of order $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_r$ respectively. Does it mean $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_r}$?

I believe it is true but proving it in rigourous manner find little hard. Neither I could get any counter example. Any kind of help will be appreciated.